# Not able to call a static method in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a class like this

```
class animal{
   static dog(){
  console.log("bark")
  }
}
module.exports = animal
```

Now If I require this file in another file 
and do 
animal.dog()
it shows me this error 
`animal.dog` is not a function

If I use to console.log animal it shows me an empty object now i want to know why it is showing this behavior

I am requiring the file as

```
const animal = require('./animal.js')
```

I have also tried object class function but then also it is showing me the empty object when I require it

Comment: Show how are you requiring that file, because that just works, and is that all your file, or do you have something else, show it if you do.

Comment: Cannot reproduce. https://codesandbox.io/s/88vnn15wr8

Comment: Either you're using `new animal` or you're requiring something else.

Comment: Is it possible that you have a dependency loop? (the file with animal include the other file)

Comment: I experienced this because I stupidly forgot the keyword 'static'. 
But once I put `static`, I confirm I no longer reproduce, either with commonjs `require` or es6 `import`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following

```js
class Animal{
  static dog(){
    console.log("bark")
  }
}
module.exports = Animal;
```

Then you need to call it as follows:

```js
const Animal = require('./animal.js');

let animal_class_obj = new Animal();
animal_class_obj.dog(); // will give you error that method not found

Animal.dog(); // this will work
```

Answer (score -1):

You will need to export instance instead of class to get member functions called directly.

```
class animal{
   dog(){
   console.log("bark")
  }
}
module.exports = new animal();
```

Now you are good to go with `animal.dog()`

Comment: downvoter, please consider commenting why it wouldn't work?

Comment: I didn't, but he wanted a static method, I guess that's why you were downvoted.